# 'web:' is not recognised as an internal or external command for Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, deployment, command-line, anaconda3

I am trying to create an app in heroku. And when I run on (anaconda command) this  > (web: gunicorn app:app) it gives me error > 'web:' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Okay, and what do you think it *should* do? And why?

Comment: That looks like something that should go in your `Procfile`. Why are you trying to run it as Python code?